Get Eventbrite page URL from Event ID
I have several event IDs from Eventbrite, e.g. 707852093667, from which I'm trying to extract a permalink in a WordPress template, leading to the event's page at Eventbrite.
I was hoping to be able to get the URL from these programatically by doing something like this:
<?php
 $eventbrite_id = '707852093667';
 echo '<a href="https://eventbrite.co.uk/e/'. $eventbrite_id .'">More Info</a>'; 
?>

But it seems all Eventbrite page URLs take the form of https://eventbrite.co.uk/e/title-of-event-as-slug-707852093667
Of course, the event ID doesn't contain the info in this URL. I was hoping there would be an ID-only way to create a link. Do I need to set up an API call to get the permalink?

There is an ID-only way to create the link.
If you use a URL in this format:
https://eventbrite.co.uk/e/707852093667

EventBrite's site will redirect you to the "full" URL in the format you mentioned in the question, i.e.
https://eventbrite.co.uk/e/title-of-event-as-slug-707852093667

So it doesn't matter which format you use, they both lead to the same place.

Thanks so much. I was sure I had tested this, since it's exactly the behaviour I was expecting. I must have got something wrong when I did, since it's working fine now. Appreciate the steer.
